# Predictions from Savedmodel (Tensorflow 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I saved an image classifier I trained on two different classes and want to classify a new image using the classifier. Once I have my model loaded what tf function do I call to return the softmax prediction of the final layer after feeding an image?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should run `model.predict(image_to_classify)`, if you just want the index of the prediction, and not the probabilities run `np.argmax(model.predict(image_to_classify))`